# Proving that the sequence of sums of digits eventually becomes constant

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

If S(n) denotes the sum of digits of n, how can I prove that for any n, the sequence n, S(n), S(S(n)),... eventually becomes constant? I understand that this is essentially just finding the digital sum of n, but I am having hard time figuring out how I would formally prove this. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, note that if a natural number $0 \leq k \leq 9$ then $k < 10^n$ for $n \geq 1$. This implies $S(n) \leq n$ for all natural numbers $n$ and if $n$ has multiple digits then $S(n) < n$. It's easy to verify this is true for single digit numbers and so the result then follows by induction. One could also argue that it is a monotonic decreasing sequence that is bounded below and so it has a limit point which must be a natural number because $S(n)$ is always a natural number.